# What are use cases for Groovy Scripting besides Java / Groovy classes?

Tags: java, scripting, groovy

I am playing around with Java, Groovy and Scala at the moment. Groovy enables to write scripts besides classes, which is often stated as a big advantage of Groovy because you can write applications and scripting with the same language.

Can you please tell me some use cases where it does make sense to use Groovy scripts?

For me, a script is something like unix shell scripts which copy files or stuff like this. Besides, I use JACL and Jython scripts for WebSphere Application Server deployments.

My question: When should I use Groovy scripts? Should I use them for copying files instead of unix shell scripts (thus, I have classes and scripts in the same language for easier maintenance) or when else should I use Groovy scripts?

Thanks.

Best regards, 
Kai

Answer (score 6):

Groovy scripts are interpreted within the JVM. This gives us the ability to dynamically modify the behavior of a program at runtime. *Runtime configurability* is an important feature in many types of applications. For example, in web applications and business process driven applications, conditional flows or branching can often be changed at runtime. Using *Groovy*, all you need is to change the script and make it available in some standard location from which the application can pick it up and execute.

There are a few other scripting languages available out there, but Groovy has the added advantage that it can interact very well with the available java objects and libraries making it a good fit within Java applications.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So it can be compared a little bit to a XML config file?! You load the Groovy script (e.g. from a file or database). If you want to change your behaviour, you just change your script and the application reloads it dynamically at runtime. Am I right?

Comment: @Kai: The second part is right. But it is not at all like an XML file. An XML file can hold only data (even metadata is data), whereas a groovy script contains instructions written using the groovy programming language.

Answer (score 6):

I have found Groovy scripts are great for tasks that change often and benefit from the extensive availability of Java libraries.  Their use allows me to respond quickly to dynamic business processes such as data integration with JDBC, file transfers with Apache Commons, and encryption with BouncyCastle.

Comment: I agree (+1). And not to mention you don't have to worry about OS-specific issues like line endings or path separators, because the underlying Java takes care of that.

Answer (score 3):

I love groovy scripts because they are the easiest way to programmatically interact with a [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) build. Just use the [Gmaven plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GMAVEN/Executing+Groovy+Code), and you can write Groovy Scripts (inline or in external files) that can modify your project structure at runtime (whereas you'd have to write a custom plugin in a separate project to do that in Java).

Answer (score 3):

Groovy scripts are also great for DSLs ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language ).

A good example of this would be the build tool Gradle ( http://www.gradle.org/ ).